# AGGREGATE Function stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run a query I get 3 rows back and the rows and tables are not equal to what I have. I counted them and I have 222 rows total. When I run the code I only get 63 and get 3 other rows back. I am only supposed to have 1 row. Seems to be when I put in the max it throws everything off. I am supposed to total all of the tables, get the total number of rows, get the last time the database has been updated and last time a stored proc was executed. I *cannot* use a `CROSS JOIN` as I know it will work with that. Any other ideas? Much appreciated!

```
SELECT
    COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME()) AS TableCount,
    SUM(SysPartn.Rows) AS 'Total rows in DB',
    MAX(SysObj.modify_date) AS 'Last time updated',
    (SysExProcStats.last_execution_time) AS 'Last time Executed'
FROM sys.objects AS SysObj
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS SysPartn ON SysObj.object_id = SysPartn.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS SysExProcStats ON SysObj.object_id = SysExProcStats.object_id
WHERE SysObj.type = 'U'
GROUP BY SysExProcStats.last_execution_time
```

Comment: Uh.... If you're getting any results from that query, it's because the object_id of your tables matches the object_id of a procedure in a different database on the same server. EDIT: to be clear, while sys.objects looks at your database, sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats looks at all your databases (see: the database_id column in your sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats). sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats is, as the name suggests, for procedures, not tables, so if you're looking for tables (type 'U'), you shouldn't really be joining sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats on object_id

Comment: EDIT: perhaps you want something like `select count(*), sum(syspartn.rows), max(sysobj.modify_date), max(Z.lastProcTime) from sys.objects sysobj join sys.partitions syspartn on sysobj.object_id = syspartn.object_id cross apply (select max(last_execution_time) from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats where database_id = db_id()) Z(lastProcTime)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LEFT JOIN**:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME()) AS TableCount,
    SUM(SysPartn.Rows) AS 'Total rows in DB',
    MAX(SysObj.modify_date) AS 'Last time updated',
    (SysExProcStats.last_execution_time) AS 'Last time Executed'
FROM sys.objects AS SysObj
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions AS SysPartn ON SysObj.object_id = SysPartn.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS SysExProcStats ON SysObj.object_id = SysExProcStats.object_id
WHERE SysObj.type = 'U'
GROUP BY SysExProcStats.last_execution_time
```